# Unable to find PlayScala (Heroku tutorial)

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework, sbt, heroku-cli

I'm new to Scala and Heroku and I'm following the Heroku getting-started guide.

I'm using Mac (10.14.6) and followed the instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-scala) to install sbt and play.

I am now on [Declare app dependencies](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-scala#declare-app-dependencies) but when I type the `sbt compile stage` command I get the following error:

```
$ sbt compile stage
[info] welcome to sbt 1.3.13 (AdoptOpenJDK Java 11.0.8)
[info] loading project definition from /Users/jack/scala-getting-started/project
/Users/jack/scala-getting-started/build.sbt:5: error: not found: value PlayScala
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
                                                 ^
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

The `build.sbt` file (provided automatically) is

```
name := """play-getting-started"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
  ws
)

libraryDependencies <+= scalaVersion("org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % _ )
```

How can I fix this error?

Thank you.

Comment: Suggestion - Don't follow that tutorial. Its outdated to the point of antiquity.

Comment: Read and learn Play 2.8.x and then you can deploy Play 2.8.x app on heroku by following - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ProductionHeroku

Comment: Have you added the PlayScala plugin in the project/plugins.sbt file? https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-seed.g8/blob/2.8.x/src/main/g8/project/plugins.sbt

Comment: @IzharAhmed OP is running `sbt 1.3.13` with `Java 11`, its highly unlikely that a 5 year old play project (from that tutorial) is going to work with this.

Comment: @sarvesheri agree that the latest play documentation should be followed, but here the issue is not adding plugin and then trying to enable it. OP needs to know this whether he is using Play 2.8 or 2.4.

Comment: Thanks for the kind suggestions. I am using Play 2.8.2. I will try the tutorial suggested by @sarveshseri ,